# Castle Windsor: How to detect registrations with a longer lifetime than their dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have found a situation you can get yourself into very easily in CastleWindsor DI regarding dependent components that are registered with different lifestyles.

Suppose we have the following class and interface:

```
public class MyThing : IMyThing
{
    public MyThing()
    {
    }
}

public interface IMyThing {}
```

This is registered as such in the relevant Windsor installer, which also includes a registration for HttpContextBase:

```
container.Register(
    Component
    .For<IMyThing>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyThing>()
    .LifeStyle.Singleton);

container.Register(
    Component
    .For<HttpContextBase>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(_ => new HttpContextWrapper (HttpContext.Current) )
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

All is well and good. But now some developer decides that MyThing now has a dependency on something in the HttpContext, so he changes MyThing to take in an HttpContextBase:

```
public class MyThing : IMyThing
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;

    public MyThing(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
}
```

This seems quite reasonable on the face of it - after all, when designing your classes you're supposed to be able to do that without giving much thought to the specifics of the dependency injection. However, in reality, we now have a subtle (but potentially serious) bug whereby one component depends on another component ***that has a shorter lifestyle than itself***.

Now, I was expecting this to throw some kind of exception in Castle Windsor, but it appears not to. It will perfectly happily give you a MyThing with whatever happened to be the current HttpContext at the time, and will continue to give you the same object for the rest of the life of your application *with the same HttpContext*.

After some Googling I haven't been able to find any Windsor configuration to do with this issue. Does anyone have any advice on this? The project that I have moved onto has an absolute dog's dinner of a DI setup, and finding these kind of issues is proving to be very hard (in the example I've given it should be pretty obvious if a controller has the wrong HttpContext, but it could be much less so in other cases).

Answer (score 0):

Castle Windsor does not throw exceptions for this but it displays it as a warning in debugger. (Open image in new tab)

[image]

Here's a test that can display it:

```
[TestFixture]
public class WindsorTests
{
    [Test]
    public void LifecycleWarningTest()
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(
                Component.For<ISingleton>().ImplementedBy<Singleton>().LifestyleSingleton(),
                Component.For<ITransient>().ImplementedBy<Transient>().LifestyleTransient()
            );

        ISingleton singleton = container.Resolve<ISingleton>();

    }

}


interface ISingleton
{

}

class Singleton : ISingleton
{
    private readonly ITransient _transient;

    public Singleton(ITransient transient)
    {
        _transient = transient;
    }
}

interface ITransient
{

}

class Transient : ITransient
{
}
```

Comment: Right, so could we write a simple check for any items in the "Potential lifestyle mismatches" collection?

Comment: I couldn't find where it is. You may want to check the source code.

Comment: Oh dear; it appears those collections are only available to the debugger, and cannot be accessed in code :(